# Lenovo T410 Camera Software

Tags: webcam, thinkpad, camera

What free software can I use to acquire a photo from the camera on the Lenovo T410? The camera drivers are properly installed and working in applications like Skype and ManyCam, but I am not sure what I can use to save a picture or video file. I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You do not actually need any extra drivers installed for the ThinkPad webcams, as they are UVC (USB Video Device Class) webcams, which use the standard Windows driver.  Basically, you can use any non-proprietary webcam software with them.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class